# Creating new users(is_instructor or is_student) by only is_staff user(admin)

Tags: django, react-native, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am building a Cross-platform mobile application Mobile learning management system using React native and Django Rest framework, where stakeholders are admin, instructor, and students. I want to have the functionality of creating users through the only admin(is_staff). So basically using custom UserManger and custom User, As I have additional attributes when I want to register a new user. Basically, I want to know how we can implement RBAC, I am a beginner, sorry if the question is very simple.

Comment: This is very broad : do you need pointers on django users management ? How to implement RBAC / AIM ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.